# Unable to read data from .csv file using D3

Tags: csv, d3.js

I have data in a .csv file that I am trying to display using D3.
My script inside the head tag has a function:

```
        function show(data) {
            console.log(data[0]);
            d3.select("body")
                .selectAll("p")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("p")
                .text(function(d) { return d.price} )                   
        }
```

In the body of the page inside a script tag I have:

```
    d3.csv('simple5.csv', show)
```

The file simple5.csv is:

```
name, price
a, 5
b, 10
c, 15
d, 20
e, 25
f, 30
g, 35
```

While the console.log function shows me the data, I am unable to see the data in the HTML page. I have tried using the d3.csv.parse and the d3.cd.parseRows functions, but then I get an error: "text.charCodeAt is not a function".

Comment: Do you have `p` elements on the page already?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove your .text() function, you can see that the p tags are getting created. Therefore, your csv format is incorrect. When I changed it to the following, it started working :
name,price

```
a,5
b,10
c,15
d,20
e,25
f,30
g,35
```

Please try.